# AMQP - Rabbit MQ usage

Tags: java, api, jms, rabbitmq, amqp

This may be a very basic question. But I am bit confused.

I know `RabbitMQ` is a `AMQP` broker (meaning `RabbitMQ` implements / uses `AMQP`). 
I used client libraries (jars) provided by RabbitMQ. Does it mean I used `AMQP` protocol which is used "internally" by `RabbitMQ` client APIs / libraries to connect to the RabbitMQ broker? Anything else I need to know about using `AMQP`?

Or is there a different route I need to follow to use `AMQP`?
How is a developer concerned about using `AMQP` other than just using the APIs of the any Message Broker like RabbitMQ, Apache QPid, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > I used client libraries (jars) provided by RabbitMQ. Does it mean I used AMQP protocol which is used "internally" by RabbitMQ client APIs / libraries to connect to the RabbitMQ broker?

Yes you have used AMQP protocol (probably); RabbitMQ isn't using internally AMQP. It uses AMQP to send messages from your application to RabbitMQ and from RabbitMQ to (your) other application; or viceversa.

> > Or is there a different route I need to follow to use AMQP?

Besides using the API you can use as an extension of Apache Camel or Spring Integration for example; it is more neat and you can use it in more parts of your application. Actually it doesn't matter how you using so long you respect the protocol.

> > How is a developer concerned about using AMQP other than just using the APIs of the any Message Broker like RabbitMQ, Apache QPid, etc?

AMQP is a protocol, just like HTTP; besides the API it defines the message format and has features as routing or queuing being served by the protocol rather by the application implementing the API.

Comment: `AMQP is a protocol, just like HTTP; besides the API it defines the message format and has features as routing or queuing being served by the protocol rather by the application implementing the API.` So are you saying Developer does "not" need to know anything about AMQP ,when "programming" / using API provided by the broker (RabbitMQ,etc)? (Of course, just being aware of the fact that the broker API uses AMQP for communication)

Comment: Of course not; when programming over HTTP (say rest web services) you don't care about HTTP (response codes for example)?